# Curried function causing error but works if not curried

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

```
export const postMoviePopular = url = dispatch => {
    const data = axios.get(url);
    dispatch(saveMoviePopular(data));
}

const saveMoviePopular = payload => {
    return {
        type: POST_MOVIE_POPULAR,
        payload
    }
}
```

This is my code which does not work because it is curried, but if it IS NOT curried like below, it works, why is this??

```
export const postMoviePopular = url => {
    return dispatch => {
        const data = axios.get(url);
        dispatch(saveMoviePopular(data));
    }    
}
```

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the way I am calling mapDispatchToProps???

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.postMDBConfig(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}`);
        this.props.postMoviePopular(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US`)
    }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        postMDBConfig: url => dispatch(postMDBConfig(url)),
        postMoviePopular: url => dispatch(postMoviePopular(url))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your first version has `=` where you really want `=>` in the first line

Comment: @Pointy, but that would throw an error.

Comment: I meant the second `=`; without that, `url` is just a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a return statement. And another arrow.

```
export const postMoviePopular = url => dispatch => {
    const data = axios.get(url);
    return dispatch(saveMoviePopular(data));
}
```

Comment: also shouldn't it be `url => dispatch =>`?